# How to turn each image in react-image-galley into a clickable link?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-image-gallery to display different merchandise, and I want each image in the gallery to be clickable and take me to it's own product page on a third-party website. I retrieve the merchandise info from the third-party website's API (right now I am just using fake data), and I should have all the info I need to implement that functionality from the API. Here is my code:

```
export default function MerchPreview() {
  const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const formattedProducts = testMerchData.results.map(product => (
      {
        originalTitle: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        original: product.images[0].url,
        thumbnail: product.images[0].url,
        slug: product.slug
      }
    ))

    setGallery(formattedProducts)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='MerchPreview'>
      <ProductGallery 
        items={gallery}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've read the docs of [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) over and over but my inexperience makes me unsure of where to even start. renderItem looks like it may do what I need but 1. the docs hardly go over it and I am unsure of how to implement it and 2. I think it may be overkill for what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for what I did https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-image-gallery-forked-k3s4v2?file=%2Fsrc%2Fimages.js%3A12%2C4

as you mentioned render item is probably the easiest way to do this just wrap your image in a a tag.   however if you don't want to roll your own, and you want to leave the default gallery you can add an on click event. unfortunately there is not an onclick event for each image. instead wrap a div around the gallery and use closest to find the image. see below

```
 <div className='MerchPreview' onClick={handleGalleryClick}>
      <ProductGallery 
        items={gallery}
      />
    </div>
```

and here is the on click.

```
 const handleGalleryClick = (event) => {
    // Find the index of the clicked item
    let target = event.target;
    while (
      target != null &&
      !target.classList.contains("image-gallery-image")
    ) {
      target = target.parentElement;
    }
    if (target) {
      const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".image-gallery-slide");
      const index = Array.from(slides).findIndex((slide) =>
        slide.contains(target)
      );
      if (index !== -1) {
        const url = gallery[index].productPageUrl;
        if (url) {
          window.open(url, "_blank");
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I ended up fiddling around enough with react-image-gallery and discovered that the onClick prop provided for the root component (rather than each individual image in the gallery) actually does function as a way to click on each individual image in the gallery (so no need to wrap the component in a div and add the onClick prop to that). From there, I was able to use the event object in a click handler function as you have shown, only instead of retrieving the index, I instead retrieved the nodeValue with the slug I needed for navigation.